# PostgreSQL: How do I join two tables based on same start and end time (timestamp without time zone)?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Okay, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026554/sql-join-tables-on-time-between-start-and-end) relevant question but it is slightly different than my case.

**Problem**

I have two similar type of tables in my PostgreSQL 9.5 database `tbl1` and `tbl2` both containing `1,274 rows`. The structure and layout of `table 1` is as follows:

**Table 1:**

```
id (integer)   start_time           end_time              my_val1 (numeric)
51             1994-09-26 16:50:00  1994-10-29 13:30:00   3.7
52             1994-10-29 13:30:00  1994-11-27 12:30:00   2.4
53             1994-11-27 12:30:00  1994-12-29 09:25:00   7.6
54             1994-12-29 09:25:00  1994-12-31 23:59:59   2.9
54             1995-01-01 00:00:00  1995-02-05 13:50:00   2.9
55             1995-02-05 13:50:00  1995-03-12 11:10:00   1.6
56             1995-03-12 11:10:00  1995-04-11 09:05:00   2.2
171            1994-10-29 16:15:00  1994-11-27 19:10:00   6.9
172            1994-11-27 19:10:00  1994-12-29 11:40:00   4.2
173            1994-12-29 11:40:00  1994-12-31 23:59:59   6.7
173            1995-01-01 00:00:00  1995-02-05 15:30:00   6.7
174            1995-02-05 15:30:00  1995-03-12 09:45:00   3.2
175            1995-03-12 09:45:00  1995-04-11 11:30:00   1.2
176            1995-04-11 11:30:00  1995-05-11 15:30:00   2.7
321            1994-09-26 14:40:00  1994-10-30 14:30:00   0.2
322            1994-10-30 14:30:00  1994-11-27 14:45:00   7.8
323            1994-11-27 14:45:00  1994-12-29 14:20:00   4.6
324            1994-12-29 14:20:00  1994-12-31 23:59:59   4.1
324            1995-01-01 00:00:00  1995-02-05 14:35:00   4.1
325            1995-02-05 14:35:00  1995-03-12 11:30:00   8.2
326            1995-03-12 11:30:00  1995-04-11 09:45:00   1.2
.....
```

In some rows, `start_time` and `end_time` may look similar but whole time window may not be equal. For example,

```
 id (integer)   start_time          end_time              my_val1 (numeric)
 54             1994-12-29 09:25:00 1994-12-31 23:59:59   2.9
 173            1994-12-29 11:40:00 1994-12-31 23:59:59   6.7
```

`Start_time` and `end_time` are `timestamp without time zone`. The `start_time` and `end_time` have to be in one year window thus whenever there was a change of year from `1994` to `1995` then that row was divided into two rows therefore, there are repeating IDs in the column `id`. Table 2 `tbl2` contains the similar `start_time` and `end_time` (`timestamp without time zone`) and column `my_val2` (`numeric`). For each row in `table 1` I need to join corresponding row of `table 2` where `start_time` and `end_time` are similar.

**What I have tried,**

```
Select 
    a.id,
    a.start_time, a.end_time,
    a.my_val1,
    b.my_val2
from tbl1 a
left join tbl2 b on 
b.start_time = a.start_time
order by a.id;
```

The query returned `3,802` rows which is not desired. The desired result is 1,274 rows of `table 1` joined with `my_val2`. I am aware of Postgres `Distinct on` clause but I need to keep all repeating `ids` of `tbl1` and only need to join `my_val2` of `tbl2`. Do I need to use Postgres Window function here. Can someone suggest that how to join these two tables?

Comment: If the start and end time in tbl2 and tbl1 are similar should you join on start_time and end_time? Also how similar are the times for tbl1.start and tbl2.start? Will equals give the desired result or should some rounding be applied to the times?

Comment: I tried: b.start_time = a.start_time AND b.end_time = a.end_time but query returned some empty rows. The problem is IDs only exist in table_1. In table 2, start_time and end_time window may be the same but they are not in the same order as table_1.

Comment: Executing Distinct on start_time and end_time in both tables returned 1,187 rows. Thus, start and end_time are not unique like IDs. I am not sure rounding will help or give desired result. I can't show all start and end_time rows here.

Answer (score 0):

why you don't add to the ON part the condition

```
ON b.start_time = a.start_time AND a.id = b.id
```

Comment: Thanks. But, IDs column only exists in table_1.

Comment: You don't have a primary key neither a forgin key on your tables, so how do you know which rows are connected to each other​?

Comment: As I said above, the start_time and end_time window are same but may not be in the same order. I cab create object_id as a new primary key column but I'm not sure the join will give the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

> For each row in table 1 I need to join corresponding row of table 2
>   where start_time and end_time are similar.

SQL query should include end_time

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.start_time, 
       a.end_time,
       a.my_val1,
       b.my_val2
  FROM tbl1 a
  LEFT JOIN tbl2 b 
    ON b.start_time = a.start_time
   AND b.end_time = a.end_time
 ORDER BY a.id;
```